# Ubunutu 12.04(precise pangolin)

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, downloads

Hello everyone can i get Ubuntu 12.04 ('precise pangolin')? I searched on google , link is there, but it couldn't download. If any has this Ubuntu please send me link or file.

Comment: As you're a new user on this site, please [accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that solves your problem best by clicking the grey round tick button on its left. Also, don't forget to spend two minutes on taking our [tour] where you learn the most important things about how this site works. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the 12.04.05 LTS `.iso` images from http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/.

Depending on your hardware, you should either download the **32 bit** version (works everywhere) or the **64 bit** version (works only with a compatible 64 bit CPU, 4GB RAM or more are recommended).

If you want a normal graphical operating system, chose a **desktop** version. The **server** version does not contain any GUI but only a terminal interface, this is probably not what you want.

---

However, 12.04 is already pretty old and its support will end in April 2017. You should install a more recent release of Ubuntu unless you have a special reason for picking 12.04:

- [14.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) (released in April 2014, supported for 5 years until April 2019)
- [15.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/) (released in October 2015, supported for 9 months until July 2016)
- [16.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) (released in April 2016, supported for 5 years until April 2021)

---

Further information about how to install Ubuntu can be found here:
[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/367990)

Answer (score 1):

You can download it via torrent from the official download page http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads